# Show table shows according to select change with dynamic options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Below is my html structure in which i am showing rows with active status and inactive status accordingly with the select change and its working fine.

But now project requirements are change and the status can be many more apart of active and inactive so i want that select options should be created according to the status of rows and i am pass some common variable to row instead of defining like this `ng-hide="transStatus=='inactive'"`

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table tr td{
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<div class="transactions_box">
    <div class="transactions_box_head clearfix">
        <h2>Transactions</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="transaction_selects">
        <select class="form-control" ng-init="transStatus==' '" ng-model="transStatus">
            <option value="">Select Action</option>
            <option value="active">Active</option>
            <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="transaction_table">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="allCheck"> Transaction ID</label></div></th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Voucher Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='inactive'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='inactive'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='inactive'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='inactive'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='inactive'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='active'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Inactive</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='active'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Inactive</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='active'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Inactive</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='active'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Inactive</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='active'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Inactive</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='active'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Inactive</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='active'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Inactive</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="transStatus=='active'">
                    <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck"> 146319483164316</label></div></td>
                    <td>18/07/2016 11:25:56</td>
                    <td>100.00</td>
                    <td>Inactive</td>
                    <td>Purchased</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can loop through all trs in tbody and add the status to an array if not already present. with that array you can populate your select field and then onchange loop tbody trs again and show/hide according to status match. need further assistance with that?

Comment: Just to clarify my understanding, you want to dynamically populate the select options based on the unique statuses in the table?

Comment: @Mic yes i want to populate the options dynamically according to table cell text and also rows will show accordingly on select change. As of now the rows are displaying on select change but i have statically mentioned that

Comment: @SimonKraus Could you please show some code for the same??

Comment: Is there a particular reason you haven't created the table with an ng-repeat directive and bound it to a model? It kind of looks like you're using angular but not really adopting it's approach. And one more question, in your actual case, are you potentially dealing with the sort of volume where you would want to paginate your rows server-side?

Comment: @Mic you can ignore that because i just mentioned here a dummy small piece of code my actual application is much bigger and i am using `ng-repeat` in that but here my focus was on only select options and rows according to that select

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Okay, I see. In that case, the answer I posted will work for you. Let me know if it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: @Mic i think the answer is brilliant just trying to understand it more as i am new to angular

Comment: @GauravAggarwal If you get stuck in any part in particular, let me know and I can add some explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117874/discussion-between-gaurav-aggarwal-and-mic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a plunker showing an approach using an Angular controller and bindings.

Here are the pieces:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dynamic Table Filter Select</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="transactions_box">
    <div class="transactions_box_head clearfix">
        <h2>Transactions</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="transaction_selects">
        <select class="form-control" ng-options="filter as filter for filter in filterSet" ng-model="selectedFilter"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="transaction_table">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="allCheck"> Transaction ID</label></div></th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Voucher Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="row in gridData">
              <tr ng-show="row.status===selectedFilter || selectedFilter === filterSet[0]">
                  <td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="allCheck "/>{{row.id}}</label></div></td>
                  <td>{{row.date}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.amount}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.status}}</td>
                  <td>{{row.voucherType}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.gridData = [ //canned data for now.
                {
                    id:146319483164316,
                    date:'18/07/2016 11:25:56',
                    amount:100.00,
                    status:'Active',
                    voucherType:'Purchased'
                },
                {
                    id:146319483164316,
                    date:'18/07/2016 11:25:56',
                    amount:100.00,
                    status:'Active',
                    voucherType:'Purchased'
                },
                //...
                {
                    id:146319483164316,
                    date:'18/07/2016 11:25:56',
                    amount:100.00,
                    status:'Inactive',
                    voucherType:'Purchased'
                }
            ];

  $scope.filterSet = $scope.gridData.reduce(function(filters, item) {
    if(filters.indexOf(item.status) === -1) {
      filters.push(item.status)
    }
    return filters;
  },['Select Action']);

  $scope.selectedFilter = $scope.filterSet[0];
});
```

My style.css is identical to your css.
Here's the plunker so you can live preview it:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Y7jbsPWVPXSjAKbb6Kr4?p=preview

So detailing what's going on, I have the data hardcoded in the controller as a javascript object for now. I'm guessing you would pull this from a dynamic source, probably in JSON, it should be pretty trivial to get it into a javascript array. Once that is populated, I create the filter options. I've (ab)used the Array.prototype.reduce to create an array of unique values. There's currently no sorting involved here, so it's going to be order-of-appearance with the "Select Action" prompt coming first. There are several ways you could do this, the point is to iterate over the data and build your array of options.

Most of the work is done by the ng-repeat directive and the row template. I think it's pretty self-explanatory, but for further reading you can look here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

You will see that I switched your ng-hide to an ng-show. Either would have worked, but I have had a "not (a) AND not (b)" type expression with ng-hide. It's really a style preference. What it's doing is taking the row.status (bound by the ng-repeat directive) which corresponds with $scope.gridData[x].status and checking whether it matches the bound $scope.selectedFilter.

If you try changing some of the statuses to new things, you will see that they appear in the select dropdown and the filtering works as expected without any further code changes.

One discussion point I would like to add: if you're dealing with a high-volume of data from the server, you will likely want to do pagination. If so, you will almost certainly also want to generate your filterSet and do the actual filtering server-side. I'll leave it at that, because I think going into it in detail is out-of-scope for this discussion, but it would significantly change how I would approach the problem.